# Check if cells match in two columns and, if they do, copy a related value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

Given a column `A` of 100 names and another `B` of numbers, where column `C` contains a subset of those numbers how might I populate column `D` with the matching name? A match is where the names in `A` and `D` are next to the same number. For example, A, B and C are inputs and D the desired output:

```
  ____A______B_______C_______D____
1 |Larry | 11111 | 22222 | Bob   |
2 |Bob   | 22222 | 44444 | Steve |
3 |Mike  | 33333 | 55555 | Jim   |
4 |Steve | 44444 |       |       |
5 |Jim   | 55555 |       |       |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try in D1 and copied down to suit:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C1,B:B,0))
```

Comment: Also to prevent having "#N/A" everywhere, you can put that function inside an if statement  For example,  =IF(C1= "", "", INDEX(A:A, MATCH(C1, B:B, 0)))

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you are looking for, but a Vlookup function should help you greatly.  I used a helper column to link C1 = A1, C2=A2 and so on.  You can hide this column if you need to.  You can then use the formula shown below in cell E1 and drag it down.  As you put numbers in column D, the name will automatically fill in column E with the matching code.

[image]